# Java Paths.get .... readAllBytes(path)) not working with relative path

Tags: java, javafx, relative-path

I am new to Java and trying to build an FX application. One of my function aims at replacing certain strings with others. The script works fine as long as I define the absolute path of the target file, but breaks when I work with the relative path.

The problem is in the method "readAllBytes", that only works with the  complete path. But I need relative path, since the folder location will vary.

The target file is in the project folder. Is there any other method I can use to read the file content, that does not require the absolute path?

Thanks a lot in advance. Below is the snippet:

```
    if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
        //this works .....
        Path path = Paths.get("//home/../../../../Target.fxml")
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8; 
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
        content = content.replaceAll("text_old" , "text_new");
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

        //this doesn't work...
        Path path = Paths.get("Target.fxml");


Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Target.fxml
```

Comment: Can you post enough code so that we know what you are doing? What is `content`? And post the complete stack trace in the question.

Comment: Title says *"not working with relative path"*, and then the first thing you should is that it *is* working with a relative path (*hint:* `"Target.fxml"` is a relative path). So, it can find the file in the current directory. You then say it works with an absolute path. You then say it doesn't work with `ClassLoader.getResource()`. Is the file supposed to be on the classpath, e.g. is the current directory on the classpath?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your patience, please see the updates above ....

Comment: Why the stacktrace says cannot find **FXMLDocument.fxml** although in your code we only see **Target.fxml** ?

Comment: Which line (in the code you posted, I can see the line number) is actually throwing this exception?

Comment: A more general question though: are you really intending to find an FXML file in the file system? Usually FXML files would be bundled as part of the application, so you would retrieve them as a resource. For example, if you bundle your application as a jar file in the usual way, the FXML file will be an entry in the jar file (so there won't be a corresponding FXML file on the file system at all). Is there a reason you're doing it this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exception root cause `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Target.fxml` does mean that the file does not exist at the given location.

If you're doing `Paths.get("Target.fxml")` you are looking in the current working directory for the file `Target.fxml`. But since the file is located in `src/javafxapplication/Target.fxml` and the program is run from a different directory `Target.fxml` can not be found.

You can check the working directory of your application using e.g.:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
```

This might very well be the `classes` directory. If you want to e.g. point from `classes` to the `src` folder you can use the following path:

```
Paths.get("../src/javafxapplication/Target.fxml")
```

**This is however bad practice since the `src` folder is normally not part of your distribution package.** You should probably copy the `Target.fxml` to another location or use Build Tools like Apache Maven to create a jar file which does include the `Target.fxml` and read the contents from the jar file using `ClassLoader.getResource()`.

Comment: Fasseg, the three dots were just to shorten the path name in my query, it is  not part of script. The complete path is /home/rainer/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication/src/javafxapplication/Target.fxml.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you're actually trying `Paths.get(" /home/rainer/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication/src/javafxap‌​plication/Target.fxm‌​l")`?

Comment: Does `new java.io.File(" /home/rainer/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication/src/javafxap‌​plication/Target.fxm‌​l").exists()` return `true` then?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the second call, that does not work, tries to locate the `Target.fxml` in the current working dir, which is not `src/javafxapplication`. Try to check the current working dir with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")));` and you will see that your program is running in `classes/` or something. Then you can modify your relative path to point from the current working dir to the `src/javafxapplication` dir

Comment: @Rainer Just as a general comment - looking for a file in the `src` directory at runtime just seems completely wrong. Most of the time the application is executed, the source folder won't be available at all. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: /home/rainer/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication/src/javafxapplication/Target.fxml works, ../rainer/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication/src/javafxapplication/FXMLDocument.fxml does not. I also need to point to the file from within the folder, since the folder location will vary ...

Comment: James, there is a checkbox that replaces selected="true" with selected="false" in the FXML file, to remember the state. The process works fine, I just have problems with the file path ....

Answer (score 5):

Got it working after all, thanks to Fasseg and others who found the time and patience to look into this. Here is the final code:

```
        Path path = Paths.get("src/javafxapplication2/PopupFXML.fxml");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
        content = content.replaceAll("old_text" , "new_text");
        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```